# DatePicker php json not functioning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, datepicker

I am trying to gather stored dates from the database and saved it into a json. I then want to use the dates in the datepicker as unavailable dates. This is what I have come up with by the datepicker isn't showing at all.

**checkDates.php**

```js
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "user";
$dbname = "eBooking";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

$sql = "select bookedDate from appointment_booked";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$checkDates = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $checkDate['dates'] = $row['bookedDate'];
       
        $checkDates[] = $checkDate;
    }

echo json_encode($checkDates);
 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

**Index.jsp**

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
 beforeShowDay: checkAvailability
 });

 })
 
 $.getJSON('checkDates.php?dld='+ id, function(json){dates=json;});

function checkAvailability(mydate){
 var myObject = dates;
  for( var x in myObject) {
           $myBadDates = new Array(myObject[x]['dates']);

   var $return=true;
   var $returnclass ="available";
   $checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', mydate);
    
   for(var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++)
    {  
       if($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate)
       {
      
     $return = false;
     $returnclass= "unavailable";
     }
     }
   
   return [$return,$returnclass];
    }
}

 
</script>



</head>
<body>
 <tr id="tr1">
 <td>Select appointment date: </td>
 <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" value="" /></td>
 </tr> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check for errors in the developer console

Comment: There isn't any errors.

Comment: Define the variable `dates`  before the Ajax call

Answer (score 0):

getJson is async so you have to wait until it done:

```
var dates;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "checkDates.php",
        data: { dld: 3 },
        success: function (json) {
            alert("success, look at the console");
            console.log(json);

            dates = json;

            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                beforeShowDay: checkAvailability
            });
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
            console.log(request);
        }
    });

function checkAvailability(mydate) {
    var myObject = dates;
    for (var x in myObject) {
        $myBadDates = new Array(myObject[x]['dates']);

        var $return = true;
        var $returnclass = "available";
        $checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', mydate);

        for (var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++) {
            if ($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate) {

                $return = false;
                $returnclass = "unavailable";
            }
        }

        return [$return, $returnclass];
    }
}
```

i have updated my code,
try with error handling

Comment: The datepicker is not appearing when I click the field.

Comment: make sure you set id variable: `'checkDates.php?dld=' + id`

Comment: what should the id variable be set as?

Comment: is there anything at the console : `console.log(json);`

Comment: Nothing is showing up. Is my code completely wrong? I tried to look through many examples and they do it a very similar way.

Comment: you had better rework your code, try logging to console, and make sure anything returns from php page.

Comment: The PHP code itself can echo out the json to the console.

Comment: did you try with $.ajax() version above, any alerts ?

Comment: Nothing. As soon as I make changes to date picker, the calendar doesn't show up anymore. I don't know if that will affect it.

Comment: can you try after changing this line: `$.getJSON('checkDates.php', function(json){alert(json);}).fail(function() {    alert( "error" );  });`